# Crop a GeoTIFF using latitude, longitude box (C# or C++)

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, geolocation, gis

**TL;DR**

I'm looking for piece of code, algo, or a lib, that can crop a GeoTIFF image file using a box of latitudes and longitudes.

**Description**

Basically, I have a large GeoTIFF (around 160mb), and I want to show it on a map in C#. Now the GeoTIFF has all the GPS data, so I can place it exactly where its required on the map. But that would take a lot of memory since the image file is huge.

**My pipeline**

A map is built up of small tiles in form of [X, Y, Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_web_map). I want to split a GeoTIFF to small tiles, and show them on a map. Here's how I can (theoretically) achieve it.

1. A map control requests tile in form of X, Y, Z.
2. X, Y, Z is converted to lat/lon ([algo](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames)).
3. Crop the GeoTIFF using the latitude/longitude box.

I believe that GDAL can do this, but as far as I know, it reads the whole file into memory dumps the output in the file system. I want it to read only the cropped area into memory, and then write it in memory as well.

Comment: Off topic for SO, I'm afraid. You can give https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ a try, though. Make sure you read their help pages so you can tailor your post to meet their requirements.

Comment: This isn't exactly a software recommendation request. I'm looking for a code, algo or a lib. Which doesn't fall in softwarerecs domain.